# Angular error: Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to write a simple modularized application. But I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'SomeComponent' imported by the
>   module 'SomeModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Basically, I do not want to import all the services and components in `app.module.ts`, I wanted to modularize the code and I failed.

This is the `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

This is nested module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [SomeService],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [SomeComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {
}
```

This is the nested component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  somes: Array<ISome>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private service: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSomes();
  }

  getSomes() {
    this.service.getSomes().subscribe(res => {
      this.somes = res;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You're trying to "import" a component in `SomeModule`.

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  SomeComponent
],
```

You *import* modules and *declare* components, which is exactly what the error message tells you -- you tried importing a directive `SomeComponent`.

> Unexpected directive 'SomeComponent' imported by the module 'SomeModule'.

Move the `SomeComponent` from `imports` to `declarations`.

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
],
providers: [SomeService],
declarations: [
  SomeComponent,
],
```

Answer (score 7):

Move your Somecomponent to declaration part.

```
NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule

  ],
  providers: [SomeService],
  declarations: [SomeComponent]

})
export class SomeModule {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue.

I created a `pipe` and put it inside a `module` so that it can be accessible by multiple components.

**What I was doing wrong?**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomDatePipe, // declarating pipe class instead of importing pipe module
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### How to fix this issue?

import `pipe-module` in `AppModule` i.e.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CustomDateModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare that component in nested module.

Try this in nested module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [SomeService],
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  exports: [SomeComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {
}
```

Comment: I can't really see any difference between the accepted answer and this one.  This code must also work